# Map Style to have no pins using Maps Platform Style Editor

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I use Google Maps in an internal web application using the JavaScript API. I programmatically plot pins for locations relevant to our customers & other data locations. However, things like restaurants, shopping locations, malls, etc. are not relevant and just clutter the map, and I'd prefer they be hidden

1. Using the `styles` map option when creating the map, I can accomplish this with the following, and the pins all go away. (current implementation)

```js
const noIconsStyle = [
    {
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ]
    }
];

var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: noIconsStyle //set map style
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions );
```

2. I can also do this using the legacy style system on the Google Maps Platform website and it works as expected, I just need to add a `mapId` option when I instantiate my map and it'll use the style I have connected to that `mapId`.

[image: Screenshot of legacy style editor]

3. However the new style editor has no "all" section. And upgrading a legacy style results in that setting being lost, and all the pins come back.
   I can try toggling the setting for all "Points of Interest", but it doesn't actually apply to *all* of them, some still show.

[image: Screenshot of style editor]

I can turn off labels for all 4 of the top level categories (Points of Interest, Political, Infrastructure, and Natural), and I *still* get pins for some stores, malls, cinema, golf courses, etc.

The reason I'm revisiting this is that currently I'm using option #1. But I want to take advantage of the new `AdvancedMarkerView` in place of the traditional `Marker` class, but that requires that the map have a `mapId`. Once I do that, I get a warning in the console that a map's `styles` property can't be set when using a `mapId`, so now option #1 is out and I'm looking at alternatives.

Am I missing something or did they break/remove the ability to hide all pins on the map with their new Map Styles?

Comment: This is a known issue that was reported in Google's Issue Tracker. You can view and star the issue to get updates on it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/321086844